# How to do a regex replace with matching case?

Tags: python, regex

When replacing words using regular expressions, is there an elegant way to indicate that I want the replacement to match the upper/lower case of the first letter of the replaced word?

```
foo -> bar
Foo -> Bar
foO -> bar
```

An example of a case-insensitive replace, but it won't correctly replace `Foo` with `Bar` (it does `bar` instead).

```
re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', 'this is Foo', flags=re.I)
# 'this is bar'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing out of the box. You need to use a replace function.

```
import re

def cased_replacer(s):
    def replacer(m):
        if m.group(0)[0].isupper():
            return s.capitalize()
        else:
            return s
    return replacer

re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', cased_replacer('bar'), 'this is foo', flags=re.I)
# => 'this is bar'
re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', cased_replacer('bar'), 'this is Foo', flags=re.I)
# => 'this is Bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer:

You can do it by using `finditer` to visit all the matches, then performing the case-matching by hand.

```
tests = (
        "11foo11",
        "22Foo22",
        "33foO33",
        "44FOO44",
)

import re
foobar = "(?i)(foo)"

for teststr in tests:
    replstr = "bar"

    newchars = list(teststr)

    for m in re.finditer(foobar, teststr):
        mtext = m.group(1)
        replchars = list(replstr)

        for i, ch in enumerate(mtext):
            if ch.isupper():
                replchars[i] = replchars[i].upper()

        newchars[m.start():m.end()] = replchars
        print("Old: ", teststr, " New: ", ''.join(newchars))
```